# Make this function return distinct results

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Alright, so I know this is a large Procedure, but my question is very simple.  I am trying to get a single instance of a Bond from this, but it is giving me each instance times the number of users in the system related to the agency since I am an administrator.  This happens at the bottom where the OR EXISTS statement is.  I just need help figuring out how to limit the results down to 1 of each bond while still getting the correct results for the amounts needed, which is why the individual join statements are necessary.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetBondAmounts
    (
    @Username varchar(20)
    )
AS
    SELECT Bond.ID BondID, (ISNULL(Powers.Amount,0) + ISNULL(Charges.Amount,0)) BondAmount,
    (ISNULL(BondFee.Amount,0) + ISNULL(Powers.Premium,0) + ISNULL(Charges.Premium,0)
    + ISNULL(Forfeiture.CostOfApprehension,0) + ISNULL(Forfeiture.AmountPaid,0) + Bond.StateTax) BondTotal,
    (ISNULL(BondFee.Amount,0) + ISNULL(Powers.Premium,0) + ISNULL(Charges.Premium,0)
    + ISNULL(Forfeiture.CostOfApprehension,0) + ISNULL(Forfeiture.AmountPaid,0) + Bond.StateTax
    - ISNULL(BalanceForgiveness.Amount,0) - ISNULL(Payment.Amount,0)) BondBalance
    FROM Bond
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UserAgency ON Bond.Agency = UserAgency.Agency
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT BondID, SUM(AmountForgiven) Amount
        FROM BalanceForgiveness
        GROUP BY BondID
    ) AS BalanceForgiveness ON Bond.ID = BalanceForgiveness.BondID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Bond, SUM(Amount) Amount
        FROM BondFee
        GROUP BY Bond
    ) AS BondFee ON Bond.ID = BondFee.Bond
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Powers.Bond, SUM(Charge.BondAmount) Amount,
        ISNULL(SUM(Charge.BondPremium), 0) Premium
        FROM Powers INNER JOIN Charge ON Powers.Surety = Charge.PowerSurety
        AND Powers.PowerPrefix = Charge.PowerPrefix AND Powers.PowerNumber = Charge.PowerNumber
        GROUP BY Bond
    ) AS Powers ON Bond.ID = Powers.Bond
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT BondID, SUM(BondAmount) Amount, SUM(BondPremium) Premium
        FROM ChargeWithoutPower
        GROUP BY BondID
    ) AS Charges ON Bond.ID = Charges.BondID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Bond, SUM(CostOfApprehension) CostOfApprehension, SUM(AmountPaid) AmountPaid
        FROM Forfeiture
        GROUP BY Bond
    ) AS Forfeiture ON Bond.ID = Forfeiture.Bond
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Bond, SUM(Amount) Amount
        FROM Payment
        GROUP BY Bond
    ) AS Payment ON Bond.ID = Payment.Bond
    WHERE UserAgency.Username = @Username
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username AND Admin = 1)
```

Comment: I take it that you are trying to find the records where `UserAgency.UserName` equals `@Username` OR, if that fails, find the record where `UserAgency.Username` equals some user from the `Users` table that matches `@Username` and `Admin=`, right?  What is the connection between the `Users` table and `UserAgency.Username`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I found my own answer to my question.  I just had to make the UserAgency the same as the other joins.  Here is how it looks:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT Agency, Username FROM UserAgency
    WHERE Username = @Username
) AS UserAgency ON Bond.Agency = UserAgency.Agency
```